# ORDER BY column that has allow null is slow. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

So really my question is **WHY** this worked.

Anyway, I had this query that does a few inner joins, has a where clause and does an order by on a nvarchar column. If I run the query WITHOUT order by, the query takes less than a second. If I run the query WITH order by, it takes 12 seconds.

Now I had a great idea and changed all the INNER JOINs to LEFT JOINs. And also included the ORDER BY clause. That took less than a second. So I remembered the difference between LEFT JOINs and INNER JOINs. INNER JOINs check for NULL and LEFT JOINs don't. So I went into the table design and unchecked "Allow Nulls". Now I run the query WITH INNER JOINs and a ORDER BY clause and the query takes less than a second. **WHY?**

From what I understand, the FROM, JOINS, WHERE, then SELECT clauses should run first and return a result set. Then the ORDER BY clause runs at the very end on the resultant record set. Therefore the query should have taken **AT MOST** a second, yes, even with the column allowing nulls. So why would the query take less than a second WITHOUT the order by clause, but take 12 seconds WITH order by clause? That doesn't make sense to me.

Query below:

```
SELECT PlanInfo.PlanId, PlanName, COALESCE(tResponsible, '') AS tResponsible, Processor, CustName, TaskCategoryId, MapId, tEnd,
CASE MapId WHEN 9 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS sor
FROM PlanInfo INNER JOIN [orders].dbo.BaanOrders_Ext ON PlanInfo.PlanName = [orders].dbo.BaanOrders_Ext.OrderNo
INNER JOIN [orders].dbo.BaanOrders ON PlanInfo.PlanName = [orders].dbo.BaanOrders.OrderNo
INNER JOIN Tasks ON PlanInfo.PlanId = Tasks.PlanId
INNER JOIN EngSchedToTimingMap ON Tasks.CatId = EngSchedToTimingMap.TaskCategoryId
WHERE (MapId = 9 OR MapId = 11 or MapId = 13 or MapId = 15)
AND([orders].dbo.BaanOrders_Ext.Processor = 'metest' OR tResponsible = 'metest')
ORDER BY PlanInfo.PlanId
```

Comment: Changing the table schema will have caused the plan to be recompiled. Can you reproduce the issue by going back in and allowing Nulls or is it no longer reproducible? If it is reproducible please post both plans.

Comment: Where is the record counts, where is the execution plan, where is the indexes?

Comment: I don't think it is a problem with nulls. It purely depends on the size of the tables (number of records in the table). Order By sorts all the records from the result.

Comment: Are you sure you got **All** the records back in under a second? Without ordering it can deliver the first bunch of records very quickly. I've certainly made this mistake...

Comment: There are no indexes in this database. The result of the query is 5 records. I'm still new at this, so I've never done an execution plan before.

Comment: And now that I've changed that column back to "allow null" it won't perform the same. I'm still getting very good performance, instead of the performance I saw yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to guess that it is due to having an index on PlanInfo.PlanId, on which you are sorting.

SQL Server could streamline collection so that it follows the index and build the rest of the columns along that order.  When the field is NULLable, the index cannot be used for sorting, because it will not contain the NULL values, which incidentally come first, so it decides to optimize along a different path.

Showing the Execution Plan always helps.  Either paste the images of the plans, or just show the text-mode plans, i.e. add the line above the query, then execute it

```
SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON;
<the query>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use the ORDER BY clause, you force the database engine to sort the results. This takes some time (especially if the result contains many rows) - thus it is possible that a query that runs 1 second without an ORDER BY clause runs 12 seconds with it. Note that sorting takes at best O(N*log(N)) time where N is the number of rows.

The reason why NULLs are generally slow is the fact that they must be treated specially. Sorting with NULLs adds more complex comparison conditions and slows the sorting down.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "Why does the ORDER BY clause cause my query to run longer?" the answer is because sorting the results is added to the query execution plan.

If you use the "Show Estimated Query Execution Plan" tool in SQL Server Studio, it will show you exactly what it thinks the SQL Server engine will do.

Comment: I read the question as "Why does disallowing NULLS in the column definition speed up the query?" Edit: Although actually there are 2 questions in there. The one asking why changing nullability worked and the other "So why would the query take less than a second WITHOUT the order by clause, but take 12 seconds WITH order by clause? "